# AWS Cognito - What is the "randomPassword" used for?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, authentication, amazon-cognito

while setting up a project in React Native using AWS Cognito UserPools, I found an interesting value was being returned for my users when logging in. When using the amazon-cognito-identity-js SDK, (github found here: https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js) and implementing the authenticateUser method from Use Case 4, the result I received back included a property on the CognitoUser object called "randomPassword". Specifically, calling:

```
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: function (result) {
        ...
        console.log("CognitoUser: " + cognitoUser);
        ...
}
```

returned a CognitoUser object that looks like this:

```
CognitoUser: {
  Session: null,
  authenticationFlowType: "USER_SRP_AUTH",
  client: {...},
  ...
  randomPassword: <SOME_LONG_STRING>
  ...
}
```

I tried finding more information from the github and through the AWS docs themselves, but can't find anything. So, does anyone knows what this randomPassword is used for? Is there a security risk for having this stored in localStorage/AsyncStorage? Thanks.